# Checking for Hex Code Type

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key, value pairs pulled from the EXIF data of a JPEG. For some JPEGs, I get this weird string for a couple of the values, and I've been trying to figure out how to deal with it. I guess it's called a binary hex code, or something like that, I haven't really been able to find a lot of information, and this is outside my normal wheelhouse.

The value looks like this:

```
>>> components_config
'\x01\x02\x03\x00'
```

Or this:

```
>>> scenetype
'\x01'
```

And its type is str:

```
>>> type(components_config)
<type 'str'>
```

And it wants to display itself like this when I try to use it:

```
>>> for c in components_config:
    print c
[]    # note, these are rectangles (connected on all sides) that
[]    # I can't copy over
[]
[]
```

I figured out that I can make it readable like this:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(components_config)
'01020300'
```

or this if it's only one hex thing:

```
>>> ord(scenetype)
1
```

But the problem I'm stuck on is how to identify if the value in the dictionary is one of these or something else? The dictionary has types `tuple`, `int`, and `string` in it. I'd like to be able to pull these values out and make them into `ints`, however, everything I've tried to identify them has failed. Here's an example:

```
>>> components_config.find('\\')
-1

>>> components_config.startswith(r'\x')
False
```

So normal string operations aren't working here. Type checking is just going to return string, which gives me nothing to work with. Are there any other methods to check if the value is this hex type?

Thanks!

I'm using 2.7, btw.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers and comments, but I'm still not able to specify when to call the `struct` method, or any other method on these specific values.

`struct.unpack(HH, var)` works to turn it into the value I want, but I can't call that on every value of the dict, because I have regular strings in there, too. How do I know that when I iterate over this specific string, it's the one I need to call `struct.unpack()` on? Something like:

```
if type(var) == 'hex':
    struct.unpack('HH', var)
```

Comment: It seems to be 4-byte integer or two 2-byte integer. try `struct.unpack('I', components_config)`, `struct.unpack('HH', components_config)`, or struct.unpack('BBBB', component_config). They give `(197121,)`, `(513, 3)`, `(1, 2, 3, 0)` receptively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another look at this, and I have a way now to see if the string I'm getting is byte code or not. I admit it's not foolproof, but it's a start:

```
foos = ['\x01\x02\x03\x00', 'regular string']
for f in foos:
    if ord(f[0]) is 1:
        print f
```

Basically, each part of the hex code is indexed separately, ie:

```
x[0] = '\x01'
```

And since all of them that I've come across so far start with `1` and none of the actual strings do, this test seems to function pretty well to filter out the results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding the string as UTF-8

```
>>> print '\x01\x02\x03\x00'.encode("utf")
☺☻♥
```

The other comments results:

```
>>> import struct
>>> print struct.unpack('HH', '\x01\x02\x03\x00')
(513, 3)
```

Not sure what data you're looking at. 
:D

Answer (score 0):

You want the struct module:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html

> This module performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings. This can be used in handling binary data stored in files or from network connections, among other sources. It uses Format Strings as compact descriptions of the layout of the C structs and the intended conversion to/from Python values.